# What is the type of QueΛ's projection operator?

Tags: types, functional-programming, operators, ocaml

In Suzuki, Kiselyov and Kameyama's recent paper [*Finally, Safely-Extensible and Efficient
Language-Integrated Query*](http://okmij.org/ftp/meta-programming/quel.pdf) they give a specification of a type-safe, extensible query language embedded in OCaml that can be translated to SQL.

Here's the algebra they use for queries, lifted from the paper.

```
module type Symantics = sig
    type α repr (* representation type *)

    val int: int → int repr
    val bool: bool → bool repr
    val string: string → string repr

    val lam: (α repr → β repr) → (α→β) repr
    val app: (α → β) repr → α repr → β repr

    val foreach: (unit→ α list repr) →
                 (α repr → β list repr) →
                 β list repr
    val where: bool repr → (unit → α list repr) → α list repr
    val yield: α repr → α list repr
    val nil: unit → α list repr
    val (@%): α list repr → α list repr → α list repr (* bag union *)

    val (=%): α repr → α repr → bool repr

    ... (* abbreviated *)

    type α obs (* observation *)
    val observe: (unit → α repr) → α obs
end
```

The projection operator `(%.)`, which is used later in the paper, is snipped in the section marked *abbreviated*. The text says:

> We use the symbol `@%` for [bag union], `=%` for equality test, and `%.` for
>   projection, whose typing is elided for brevity. See our code for more
>   details.

Dutifully I looked at [the code](https://bitbucket.org/knih/quel/src/dafb919cbbcbd952d0b8f28952b858cbb80b86af/src/quel_sym.mli?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), but the declaration of `%.` is nowhere to be seen.

What is the correct type of `%.`? Was it removed from the final version of the code? If so, what replaced it?

Answer (score 3):

I think, it is in [quel_sql.ml](https://bitbucket.org/knih/quel/src/dafb919cbbcbd952d0b8f28952b858cbb80b86af/src/quel_sql.ml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#quel_sql.ml-127)

```
val ( %. ) : ('a -> 'b term) -> string -> 'a -> 'c term
```

This file doesn't have corresponent .mli and OCaml deduces module's signature himself. You can load generated cmo file to the toplevel, use ocamlbrowser or merlin to get the signture of this symbol. I did the first and copypasted the signture here, so it doesn't present in the sources (you will not find it).

Comment: I don't think that's the one. It's an implementation, not a declaration, and it's tied to [`term`](https://bitbucket.org/knih/quel/src/dafb919cbbcbd952d0b8f28952b858cbb80b86af/src/quel_sql.ml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#quel_sql.ml-10)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, you don't need to declare values in OCaml, as the language can always infer the type. So sometimes people do not write `mli` files, allowing a compiler to infer them by itself. So there is no explicit declaration.

Comment: `ivg` I'm looking for the `signature` - the interface a client will be using, not the implementation in terms of SQL.

Comment: As ivg have said, OCaml generates signature himself if a mli files is omitted.